# Remove Options from Select Field with Time Comparison

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to remove time options from a select field based on time comparison and for some reason only every other option is removed. Everything after 17:00:00 is correct.

What em I missing?

**My time options:**

```
<select id="mytimes">        
    <option value="14:00:00">2:00 PM</option>
    <option value="14:15:00">2:15 PM</option>
    <option value="14:30:00">2:30 PM</option>
    <option value="14:45:00">2:45 PM</option>
    <option value="15:00:00">3:00 PM</option>
    <option value="15:15:00">3:15 PM</option>
    <option value="15:30:00">3:30 PM</option>
    <option value="15:45:00">3:45 PM</option>
    <option value="16:00:00">4:00 PM</option>
    <option value="16:15:00">4:15 PM</option>
    <option value="16:30:00">4:30 PM</option>
    <option value="16:45:00">4:45 PM</option>
    <option value="17:00:00">5:00 PM</option>
    <option value="17:15:00">5:15 PM</option>
    <option value="17:30:00">5:30 PM</option>
    <option value="17:45:00">5:45 PM</option>
    <option value="18:00:00">6:00 PM</option>
    <option value="18:15:00">6:15 PM</option>
    <option value="18:30:00">6:30 PM</option>
    <option value="18:45:00">6:45 PM</option>
    <option value="19:00:00">7:00 PM</option>
    <option value="19:15:00">7:15 PM</option>
    <option value="19:30:00">7:30 PM</option>
    <option value="19:45:00">7:45 PM</option>
    <option value="20:00:00">8:00 PM</option>
  </select>
```

**My Javascript:**

```
var t = document.getElementById('mytimes');
var t2 = "17:00:00";
for (var i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
  if (t[i].value < t2) {
    t[i].remove();
  }
}
```

**My Results**

```
<option value="14:15:00">2:15 PM</option>
<option value="14:45:00">2:45 PM</option>
<option value="15:15:00">3:15 PM</option>
<option value="15:45:00">3:45 PM</option>
<option value="16:15:00">4:15 PM</option>
<option value="16:45:00">4:45 PM</option>
<option value="17:00:00">5:00 PM</option>
<option value="17:15:00">5:15 PM</option>
<option value="17:30:00">5:30 PM</option>
<option value="17:45:00">5:45 PM</option>
<option value="18:00:00">6:00 PM</option>
<option value="18:15:00">6:15 PM</option>
<option value="18:30:00">6:30 PM</option>
<option value="18:45:00">6:45 PM</option>
<option value="19:00:00">7:00 PM</option>
<option value="19:15:00">7:15 PM</option>
<option value="19:30:00">7:30 PM</option>
<option value="19:45:00">7:45 PM</option>
<option value="20:00:00">8:00 PM</option>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/45bepjnp/

Comment: Provided answer below will work too..Both have different approaches..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `.childNodes` to select `option` `.childNodes` of `#mytimes`, `.parentElement` to select `select` element, `.removeChild()` to remove `option` element where `value` is less than `17:00:00`

```html
<select id="mytimes">
  <option value="14:00:00">2:00 PM</option>
  <option value="14:15:00">2:15 PM</option>
  <option value="14:30:00">2:30 PM</option>
  <option value="14:45:00">2:45 PM</option>
  <option value="15:00:00">3:00 PM</option>
  <option value="15:15:00">3:15 PM</option>
  <option value="15:30:00">3:30 PM</option>
  <option value="15:45:00">3:45 PM</option>
  <option value="16:00:00">4:00 PM</option>
  <option value="16:15:00">4:15 PM</option>
  <option value="16:30:00">4:30 PM</option>
  <option value="16:45:00">4:45 PM</option>
  <option value="17:00:00">5:00 PM</option>
  <option value="17:15:00">5:15 PM</option>
  <option value="17:30:00">5:30 PM</option>
  <option value="17:45:00">5:45 PM</option>
  <option value="18:00:00">6:00 PM</option>
  <option value="18:15:00">6:15 PM</option>
  <option value="18:30:00">6:30 PM</option>
  <option value="18:45:00">6:45 PM</option>
  <option value="19:00:00">7:00 PM</option>
  <option value="19:15:00">7:15 PM</option>
  <option value="19:30:00">7:30 PM</option>
  <option value="19:45:00">7:45 PM</option>
  <option value="20:00:00">8:00 PM</option>
</select>
<script>
  var t = document.getElementById("mytimes").childNodes;
  var t2 = "17:00:00";
  for (var i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {        
    if (t[i].tagName === "OPTION" && t[i].value < t2) {
      t[i].parentElement.removeChild(t[i]);
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: this seems to be correct but for some reason, it is not working for me locally. Any suggestions? The suggested QuerySelectorAll is working, however I was hoping for the `for` as it should be faster.

Comment: @WayBehind See updated post. Can you describe "not working" ?

Comment: Getting the same results as before without the `.childNodes`

Comment: @WayBehind Where is `javascript` placed in document ? Can you create a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net or plnkr http://plnkr.co to demonstrate ?

Comment: It works here and and on codepen but still not working for me locally. I need to look through my code if there is something else causing the issues. Thanks for the help! http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qZNPaL

Comment: FYI my local issues were caused by Django's `spaceless` tag and your original version is working just fine. Thanks again!  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#spaceless